# How to Remove Quotes from Excel VBA Results

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning (if you can call it that) Excel VBA as I go. The script I am using is resulting in quotes around each resulting exported file. For example, I would like the result to be a TXT files that reads HELLO WORLD, but it is resulting rather in "HELLO WORLD" with quotes. Can anyone guide me as to how to edit the script? Here it is:

```
Sub ExportToTXT()
  Dim wsData As Variant
  Dim myFileName As String
  Dim FN As Integer
  Dim p As Integer, q As Long
  Dim path As String
  Dim myString As String
  Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
    
  lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  path = "C:\Users\Mini Gyu\Desktop\GE-Region-Folders\"
  
  For p = 8 To lastcolumn
    wsData = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, p).Value
    'If wsData = "" Then Exit Sub
    myFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, p).Value
    myFileName = myFileName & ".txt"
    myFileName = path & myFileName
    'MsgBox myFileName
    myString = ""
    For q = 7 To lastrow
      myString = myString & Cells(q, p)
    Next q
    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN
    Write #FN, myString
    Close #FN
  Next p

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace:

```
Write #FN, myString
```

with

```
Print #FN, myString
```

Comment: You're like a ninja on here. I just posted this! Thank you, again~ I'll get this in time.